# How to ask the flight attendant for more airplane meals if there are still leftovers?

Tags: word-requests, phrase-request

Can anyone help me? I want to emphasize the word "leftover" so I do not sound so greedy. I also felt that it would be a waste since most of the meals needed to be thrown away if it is not consumed after they were heated.

Comment: you can ask: "Can I order another meal if there are any left?" --  "如果还有剩余，我可以再点餐吗？" (Indicating you will pay for it)

Comment: You can use English. It is **mandatory** for flight attendants to be able to speak fluent English.

Answer (score 3):

Good:
你好，请问飞机餐还有多余的吗，我可以再要一份吗，谢谢。

Bad:
喂，再来一份，我没吃饱。

In my opinion, as long as you use "请", "可以..吗", "谢谢" as the way in English,
and ask a flight attendant after their regular meal service with smile,
it is definitely a reasonable request.
A normal anwser would be: "好的，我帮您看下，请稍等".

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the following words for the adjective *leftover*:

- [剩余](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%89%A9%E9%A4%98#Chinese)

> the rest; remainder; surplus

- [多余](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A4%9A%E9%A4%98#Chinese)

> superfluous; unnecessary; surplus; uncalled-for; spare; excessive; redundant

- [富余](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%AF%8C%E9%A4%98#Chinese)

> to have more than needed; to have an abundance of; to be in surplus

---

You can consider these following words for the noun *leftovers*:

- [剩饭](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%89%A9%E9%A3%AF)

> leftover food; leftovers

- [剩菜](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%89%A9%E8%8F%9C)

> leftover food; leftovers

---

A more colloquial way to imply this would just be to simply ask:

- 可以加餐吗？
- 可以再来一份吗？